# Sharing of data received via JSON to other files

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a problem to share data received by a personal API via axios.post:

On my initial File, i have:

```
    axios
        .post('myAPIURL', this.state)
        .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.token)
```

I need to share response.data.token with other files to use this header. For example, on second file:

```
    const res = await axios.post('myAPIURL', { hello: 'world' }, {
  headers: {
    'token': // I need for the response.data.token here
  }
});
```

As there is an exchange of files, I am losing data and I am unable to simply export them.
Help me, plz!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a context to give this to all of your other components without prop-drilling.

```
// app.js

const TokenContext = React.CreateContext(null)

export default () => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState()
    // other stuff

    useEffect(() => {
        const getToken = () => {
            // get the token via your api call
            const { data: { token }} = await axios.post('myAPIURL', this.state)
            setToken(token)
        }
    }, [])


    return <TokenContext.Provider value={token}> 
        <ChildComponent />
     </TokenContext.Provider>
}

// childComponent.js
export default () => {
    const token = useContext(TokenContext)
}
```

Now you can pass the token from any component file you like. You could also store in local/session state if you want, but contexts are a more React way of sharing data with other components.